# ASP.NET Why app.MapFallbackToController take higher priority than Controllers using ApiVersion attribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use API versioning feature on an ASP.NET core API.

I added API version settings:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.ConfigureLogging((c, l) =>
{});

IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;

services.AddControllersWithViews();

services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then controllers:

```
app.MapControllers();

// fallback
app.MapFallbackToController("InvalidURL", "Fallback");

app.Run();
```

For the controller, it is like:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{v:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Get(){
    return Ok("Yes");
  }
}
```

And the Fallback controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FallbackController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult InvalidURL()
    {
        return NotFound("Invalid url");
    }
}
```

The problem is when reaching the API with `/api/v1/weather`, it always goes to the fallback controller. If I comment out the `MapFallbackToController`, the WeatherController works fine, but now I can't handle invalid endpoints. If I don't use `[apiversion]` attribute, the WeatherControll works fine and can handle invalid endpoint, but I want to use versioning.

Why this happens, or Any advice?

Comment: I used your code but route goes right. Could you share your program.cs file and the controller method. Remember to remove the sensitive information.

Comment: @Ronaldoz, Thanks for testing!! I added all the necessary code above, however I don't think there is something special here.

Comment: I am using .net7 and what’s your .net version? I tried again with your new code, but it is still right. I got the weather and the fallback of invalid url worked as expected.

Comment: @Ronaldoz, I added Fallback controller also above. I created another empty project using exactly the same code above, and I still have the save problem. I was using .net 6.016 but same problem when using .net 7.05

Comment: Are you using the package **AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning**, which is deprecated? I reproduce your problem with the package. If so, try unistall and instead use **Asp.Versioning.Mvc**.

Comment: @Ronaldoz, Ah, you found the problem, Thank your so much!! **Asp.Versioning.Mvc** need .NET 7 but I want to use .NET 6 instead, so I will use some tricks then. Not easy to find out that this is the problem, Good Job!!

Comment: @Ronaldoz, Interesting thing happen!! when using **Asp.Versioning.Mvc**, it can't distinguish different version of the same endpoint and can't tell you nonexistent version, so this new package is also having bug. Back to the **AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning**, I found out that if you use version >=2, it works find and can tell you those version not exist, ONLY v1 is Not Found, Sooo Funny!!

Comment: @Ronaldoz, and that is because this `options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);`, so v1 is not found, so my trick is set it to `new ApiVersion(0, 0)`, then `/api/v1/weather`, and `/api/v2/weather` and **invalid endpoint** are all working now, happy!!

Answer (score 0):

After done a lot of testing, I would say this is a bug on `AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`.

The problem here is because the default version takes a low priority than the fallback endpoint since the default version it set to is

```
options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
```

If set the default version to 0:

```
options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(0, 0);
```

then controller endpoints set to use v1, v2, ..., they will all work fine.